# how to copy java compiler errors to a file in windows

Tags: java, cmd, copy, file-copying

I am using windows command prompt to compile a Java code. I want to send the compiler error stacktrace to my friend. Is there a way to copy the compiler stacktrace to a file.

I tried

- `javac helloworld.java > file.txt` to copy to a file and
- `javac helloworld.java | clip` to direct the output to clipboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redirect command output into files with `>`

```
javac helloworld.java > file.txt 2>&1
```

`2>&1` redirects `stderr` (2) to `stdout` (1) and both get redirected to `file.txt`.

Note that you can also use `>>` instead of `>` to append content if you do not want to overwrite the file for every run of the command.

Comment: 1 refers to std output and 2 to std error streams or file handles, so we are redirecting the error output from the java compiler to the standard output and all that to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can just write:

```
javac myFile.java
java ClassName > filename.txt 2>&1
```

Edit: You'll need to add the "2>&1" for error output